# Where to create avoid global variables when creating objects in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a simple menu function that i want to call from my main_program() function. The code also includes a class called `Writing` which I'm trying to make an object of inside the `main_program()`. The reason for this is that I've heard that it's preferable to avoid global variables. However this doesn't work and I get the answer: `NameError: name 'writing_obj' is not defined`

When I create the object outside the `main_program()` everything works fine so I guess is that I have to return my object `writing_obj` from the `main_function()` somehow?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
class Writing:
    def writing_something(self):
        print("I'm learning Python ")

def menu():
    while True:
        val = int(input("1. Write a sentence 2. Quit "))
        if val == 1:
            writing_obj.writing_something()

        elif val == 2:
            print("The program shuts down. See ya! ")
            break

        else:
            print("Sorry, I din't get that! ")
            continue


def main_program():
    writing_obj = Writing()
    menu()

main_program()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writing_obj` is defined within the `main_program()` function and is not declared to be global.  I would suggest using function arguments:

```
...
def menu(writing_obj):
    ...

def main_program():
    writing_obj = Writing()
    menu(writing_obj)
```

You *could* instead put `global writing` at the beginning of the `main_program()` definition, but as you said, global variables are not recommended.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!